# Как убрать фон у закругленных кнопок в customtkinter если они должны быть поверх изображения фона?

Tags: python, customtkinter

С размещением фона проблем нет (это просто градиент подходящий по размеру).
А вот с помещением на него закругленных виджетов проблема:

[image: Вот такая штука неприятная]

Вот мой код, немного изменён для понимания сути:

```py
import customtkinter as ctk
from PIL import Image

ctk.set_appearance_mode('dark')


class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.geometry('470x640')
        self.title('ctk app')
        self.resizable(False, False)

        # создаём и размещаем фон
        self.background = ctk.CTkImage(dark_image=Image.open('images/dark_theme/background.png'),
                                       light_image=Image.open('images/light_theme/background.png'), size=(470, 640))
        self.background_label = ctk.CTkLabel(master=self, image=self.background,)
        self.background_label.grid(row=0, column=0)

        # self.main_frame = ctk.CTkFrame(self)
        # self.main_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')

        # делаем кнопку вкл/выкл и размещаем её
        self.activate_btn_image = ctk.CTkImage(Image.open('images/dark_theme/active_button.png'), size=(200, 200))
        self.activate_btn = ctk.CTkButton(self, text='', width=100, height=100,
                                          corner_radius=20, bg_color='transparent')
        self.activate_btn.grid(row=0, column=0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

То-есть даже `bg_color="transparent"` не работает, либо же есть какой-то нюанс который я не нашёл.
Благодарю.

Comment: Вам надо установить bg_color="цвет фона изображения", так как прозрачность действует и на слой изображения.

Comment: Возможно я не понял ваш ответ, добавил в background_label bg_color='transparent', и не получилось.